# Blazor Wasm AuthorizeView

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am using AuthorizeView to display the Dashboard button if the user has the admin role. The problem is that after authentication the button does not display. Only after I refresh the browser the button becomes visible. Is there a better approach to make this in razor view?

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="@_roles">
     <Authorized>
          <ul class="nav">
               <li><a href="/dashboard" class="nav-link"> Dashboard</a></li>
          </ul>
     </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: I have tested this and using a field works. I suggest it’s the contents of the `_roles` field. Either async loading, or the contents don’t match the users role claims. You could for debugging purposes temporarily display the users role claims and the contents of `_roles`. FYI: if you are not displaying an alternative, you can remove `<Authorized>` and `</Authorized>`. Roles are not setup by default, there are a few steps to set it up.